# exclude certain keywords without using "?!"

Tags: xml, regex

I'm trying to exclude certain keywords on logserver but apparently, it doesn't receive characters like ?! which is i need to make negation. Meanwhile, to search exact keywords i use pattern like these:

```
            [/^SMTP$/]{4}|[/^THROTTLED$/]{9}
```

to search the words SMTP and THROTTLED, but how can i exclude them without using characters like ! or ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried escaping them with a backslash ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV:Can you show me how?

Comment: Hmmm, i now see the problem, what about `[/(^SMTP$){0}/]{4}|[/(^THROTTLED$){0}/]{9}` ?

Comment: What I mean is to use `(^SMTP$){0}` instead of `(?!^SMTP$)`.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV:it didn't work ...

Comment: Try to escape it like this: `\?\!`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: THe answer of JonM below was very close to the solution. It's just I need also to exclude the letters of t,h,r,o,l,e,d,s,m,p as well so that I will exclude only exact words of SMTP and THROTTLED. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MikeM: I'm using XML

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a flavor of regex that supports look-ahead then I suggest using something like this:

```
^(?:(?!\b(?:THROTTLED|SMTP)\b).)*$
```

Make sure you run this in multi-line mode (usually the default for implementations of regex).

If you cant use the the characters `!` or `?` then perhaps you should make a copy of the log file and replace any of the lines that match the following expression with nothing:

```
^.*?\b(THROTTLED|SMTP)\b.*$
```

Then you will be left with the lines that **don't** have the strings "SMTP" or "THROTTLED".

Comment: That's very close. I tried to use this [^*\bTHROTTLED|SMTP\b*$] and it will exclude SMTP and THROTTLED but I saw that the letters begin with t,h,ro,l,e,d,s,m,p were also excluded. How can i possibly exclude exact words then? thanks in advance